# Get Variables of an Array that is in an Array (thats maybe serialized)

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, serialization

How do i get Variables out of Array that is in an Array?
And do i still have to unserialize it?
I just need "Auswahl01" and "Auswahl02" as an Variable.

Here´s the Array:

```
array(1) { [0]=>
        array(1) { [0]=>
            array(5) { ["cssClass"]=>
                string(8) "checkbox" ["required"]=>
                string(9) "undefined" ["title"]=>
                string(7) "Auswahl" ["values"]=>
                array(2) { [2]=>
                    array(2) { ["value"]=>
                        string(9) "Auswahl01" ["baseline"]=>
                        string(9) "undefined" } [3]=>
                    array(2) { ["value"]=>
                        string(9) "Auswahl02" ["baseline"]=>
                        string(9) "undefined" } } ["id"]=>
                string(11) "app_auswahl"
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Walk the array and get the value that you want...`$arr[0]['values'][0]['value'];`, `$arr[0]['values'][1]['value'];`

Comment: no need to unserialize it, just loop or access it directly like a normal array

Comment: And how do i walk an array exactly?

Comment: just use a foreach loop, sidenote: use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`

Comment: by the way, you want `Auswahl01` and `Auswahl02` as a variable? what does that mean?

Comment: It´s german an just mean "Choice01".

Comment: .. and i want to put it in an "select field" as checkbox option. But i´m still don´t know how to get it in an Variable. Or use the foreach loop for that. I had a look here but i don´t now how to transcribe it to what i need to do. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finnaly i found the failure.

*Ohgodwhy* was close.
*Gohst* also but i didn´t get it to work that way.

Here´s the Final answer:

Somehow the first Array needs to mentioned as well:

```
echo $arr[0][0]['values'][2]['value'];
echo $arr[0][0]['values'][3]['value'];
```